# In the unanswered questions page, the asker of self-deleted question still shows as most recent modifier for a question

Tags: bug

I noticed on the unanswered questions page that in a couple cases, there were users with exactly 1 rep listed as the last modifier of a question. However, on the question page itself, there was no evidence of an answer, comment, or edit from the user, and the last edited user would be somebody else entirely.

eg. As of right now, the unanswered questions page indicates that Question /20713521/ was last edited by /1459471/quole (who asked and deleted an answer), but the question page indicates it was last edited by /199217/david

Answer (score 2):

The "modified [x] ago" indicator that appears next to a question when you look at unanswered questions, or active questions, indicates any modification that happened to the question itself or *to the answers associated with the question*. When someone deletes their answer, they become the user who last modified.

At your rep level you won't see their deleted answer. At >=10K of reputation, you'll be able to see it.